# ASP.NET core app authenticating with AAD: it is possible to retrieve additional user properties/attributes as claims?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have created an `ASP.NET Core` application that successfully authenticates users with `Azure AD` and have seen that for an authenticated user an instance of type `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` is returned containing a single identity of type `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` with a Type property valued "**preferred_username**" that carries the user's UPN. Among the claims that are returned there is for example one with its Type property valued "name" which seems to contain the user's display name. I was wondering if there is a way to have other users' attributes/properties also returned in the form of claims.

Comment: we need to use [ms graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response) here.  Since you already integrated AAD into your asp.net core app, you can simplely add ms graph sdk into your app as well, then use graph client to call the api and get what you want. Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/Startup.cs#L35).

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is a way to have other user's
> attributes/properties also returned in the form of claims.

Obviously you can retrieve optional claims within your token using azure active directory. To achieve that you would need few settings in [Token configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims) under azure active directory blade.

**What Additional Claim can be added:**

Currently, [you can include these optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set) in your both [idToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#optionalclaims-type), [accessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#optionalclaims-type) and [saml2Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#optionalclaims-type)

**Settings For Optional Claims:**

If you would like to [include additional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims) within your token you ought to [configure as following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims):

Select Token configuration in your app:

[image]

Select Add optional claim and Include your claims:

[image]

You should have profile access permission:

[image]

Check your Manifest if the claims added accordingly:

[image]

Now You can Call Optional Claims which are available [ClaimTypes Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes?view=net-7.0):

[image]

**Note:** You can check the [available claims fields witin ClaimTypes Class here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes?view=net-7.0#fields).

Code Snippet:

You can implement within your application as following:

```cs
 var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
 var givenName = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
 var email = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
 var country = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Country)?.Value;
```

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#optional-claims-example) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#optional-claims-example)

Comment: Farid, great answer and I loved how you started it "Obviously you can retrieve optional claims.....". I wouldn't say that it's obvious or given for granted that you can add claims but none the less your confidence made me smile and laugh :)
BTW the display name gets returned by default and its type is simply "name" and does not appear among the values available in ClaimTypes

Comment: Thanks for your response, as I explained we can the optional claimas which are available within [`azure active directory optional claims set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set).